# How to make a mesh to bend animate from the middle axis without influencing the edges of the mesh

Tags: modeling, animation

I'd like to modify the bend of this straight line from the middle, so it can make a rounded curve.
I have attached an example below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Curve Modifier**.
First **align** your object in edit mode with your **X axis**.
Add a **NURBS Curve** and in the Curve Data check the options:

- **Shape:** Curve Deform > Stretch
- **Shape:** Curve Deform > Bounds Clamp
- **Active Spline:** Endpoint > U

In Edit Mode delete the 3rd point and move the 2nd point to the center/

Select your object and add **Curve Modifier** and choose your NURBS Curve as a **Curve Object**.

Now you can move the mid point of your curve and deform the mesh object.

[image]

If you want to move, rotate and scale the objects around you can Parent the Mesh object to the NURBS curve and transform the Parent object the way you like.

Comment: Thank you Rumen, excellent method!